# Altair Widgets not working in Pycharm - troubleshooting tips needed

Tags: python, pycharm, altair

I am playing around with Altair 5.0 using Pycharm (Python 3.11) and my code is spinning  after the first two lines below (runs continuously without failing, can't run other steps). The code is meant to produce a scatterplot with a dropdown menu to select between hospitals.  This is bewildering, the only thing I can think of is the documentation I am following (https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html) is using Jupyter Notebooks setup and I wonder if syntax in Pycharm needs to be different.

```
input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=\['Hospital 1', 'Hospital 2'\], name='Hospital')
selection = alt.selection_point(fields=\['hospital'\], bind=input_dropdown)


splot2 = (
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
x=alt.X('Risk', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
y=alt.X('Cost', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
color = alt.condition(
selection,
alt.Color('hospital:N').legend(None),alt.value('lightgray')
)
).add_params(selection)
)
```

Alternatively, I have tried the following (putting the selection and input_dropdown into encode section).  This produces an html file but upon opening I get a JSON error related to the parameter.  I think the add_params(selection) bit is the problem.  Any advise is appreciated.

```
splot2 = (
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
x=alt.X('Risk', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
y=alt.X('Cost', scale=alt.Scale(zero=False)),
color = alt.condition(
alt.selection_point(fields=\['hospital'\], bind=alt.binding_select(options=\['Hospital 1',    'Hospital 2'\], name='Hospital'))
,
alt.Color('hospital:N').legend(None),alt.value('lightgray')
)
).add_params(selection)
)
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with PyCharm, but I suggested filing them as a bug report with them if you can get your code to work in jupyter lab without issues